# take a picture of sb. vs take a picture for sb

Tags: prepositions

take a picture of sb. vs take a picture for sb.

I feel "of" means that sb. is the subject of the picture you're taking.
while "for" means something else could be the subject of the picture.
Am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: To take a picture *for* someone is to photograph a subject as a favor or service for that person. For example, before the rise of the selfie, it was common for a tourist to hand his or her camera over to a stranger so that the stranger could take a picture of the tourist in front of some sight. Taking a picture with one's own camera, so as to document something for the benefit of another who could not be present, is another instance.

Comment: As a side issue. sb. and sth. are not abbreviations known to most native English speakers. They are usually found in EFL dictionaries and websites.

Comment: So you guys would write somebody and something in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out with examples the comments already given:

*He took a picture of John* means he photographed John.

*He took a picture for John* means he photographed an unspecified subject (it might conceivably be John himself but it could be anything at all) as a service to John.